# ZeroMQ: Many-to-one no-reply aynsc messages

Tags: zeromq

I have read through the zguide but haven't found the kind of pattern I'm looking for:

1. There is one central server (with known endpoint) and many clients (which may come and go).
2. Clients keep sending hearbeats to the server, but they don't want the server to reply.
3. Server receives heartbeats, but it does not reply to clients.
4. Hearbeats sent when clients and server are disconnected should somehow be dropped to prevent a heartbeat flood when they go back online.

The closet I can think of is the DEALER-ROUTER pattern, but since this is meant to be used as an async REQ-REP pattern (no?), I'm not sure what would happen if the server just keep silent on incoming "requests." Also, the DEALER socket would block rather then start dropping heartbeats when the send High Water Mark is reached, which would still result in a heartbeat flood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PUSH/PULL` pattern should give you what you need.

```
# Client example
import zmq

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, client_id):
        self.client_id = client_id
        ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
        self.socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        self.socket.connect("tcp://localhost:12345")

    def send_heartbeat(self):
        self.socket.send(str(self.client_id))


# Server example
import zmq

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
        self.socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
        self.socket.bind("tcp://*:12345")  # close quote

    def receive_heartbeat(self):
        return self.socket.recv() # returns the client_id of the message's sender
```

This PUSH/PULL pattern works with multiple clients as you wish. The server should keep an administration of the received messages (i.e. a dictionary like `{client_id : last_received}` which is updated with `datetime.utcnow()` on each received message. And implement some housekeeping function to periodically check the administration for clients with old timestamps.

Comment: I tried this but it seems it's the PULL socket that connects and the PUSH that binds?

Comment: I would connect the clients and bind the server. The socket type should not prevent this, I just tested bind() on a PULL socket and connect() on a PUSH socket to confirm.

Comment: You are right. I tested it before and it didn't work, I think it was because I was using czmq and didn't prepend ">" for connecting and "@" for binding so czmq defaulted to the PULL-connect-PUSH-bind pattern.

Comment: Just want to mention that I found a way to avoid lots of queued heartbeats flooded the server when clients that has been offline for a while come back: the client can periodically disconnect from the server and then reconnect, so that any queued messages are dropped. Not elegant, but works for me.

Comment: You can also look at the high watermark socket option (zmq.HWM) to limit the backlog.

Comment: The problem is the PUSH socket just blocks (rather then drops messages) when HWM is reached. http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket

Comment: On the client, you can use `socket.send(zmq.NOBLOCK)` and catch the `zmq.Again` exception which is raised when sending to a socket above the watermark. By the way, this situation should only occur when the server is gone.

Comment: But I'm writing in C with czmq, which seems to have hid all low-level options... I haven't found a way to specify the NOBLOCK flag yet. Yes I'm indeed worrying about when the server is gone _and comes back some time later_, and then gets overwhelmed by all the queued heartbeats.

Comment: Nonblocking send in czmq: http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-msg-send (parameter `ZMQ_DONTWAIT`); socket options: http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-setsockopt (option name: `ZMQ_SNDHWM`).

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, it is [czmq](http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:_start) that I'm using.